# I downloaded malware called extended icons from skype - removal?

Tags: macos, skype, malware

I got this as a skype message:

"Your skype does not support extended icons. Please download the extension here: " (skypemoticonscomplete dot com)

And then went to the url and downloaded/installed...which I immediately regretted as it became quite clear this is a malware/trojan/virus.

So far it has:

- added this icon to my firefox:

[image]

- It also has opened 2 drives under the devices section in finder:

  - skypEmoticons
  - maccaptain

I found windows removal advice for windows, but not for mac.

But, nothing for mac - was hoping somebody had a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Dang. Sorry to hear about the hassle.

You may get some mileage out of ClamXav from the malware/antivirus side:

http://www.clamxav.com/

Additionally, you may want to run AdwareMedic to search out and remove any adware that may additionally have been deposited:

http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php